# Is this code doing multiple instantiations and how to avoid it?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have some code that looks like follows

**Convert.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>

class Converter
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  static inline void to_type(const char* bytes, T& val);
  static inline void to_int(const char* bytes, int& val);
};

#include "converter.inl"
```

**Convert.inl**

```
template <typename T>
void Converter::to_type(const char* bytes, T& value)
{
    auto numberOfBytes = sizeof(T);
    if (numberOfBytes == 8)
    {
        value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
    }
    else if (numberOfBytes == 4)
    {
        value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
    }
    else if (numberOfBytes == 2)
    {
        value = (T)(*(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
    }
    else {
        assert(false);
    }
}

void Converter::to_int(const char* bytes, int& value)
{
  to_type(bytes, value);
}
```

**Userofconverter.hpp**

```
#pragma once

bool isConverterUsed(const char* bytes);
```

**Userofconverter.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "converter.hpp"

bool isConverterUsed(const char* bytes)
{
  int myIntValue = 0;
  Converter::to_type(bytes, myIntValue);
  std::cout << "myIntValue: " << myIntValue << std::endl;
  return true;
}
```

**Anotheruserofconverter.hpp**

```
#pragma once

bool isConverterUsedAgain(const char* bytes);
```

**Anotheruserofconverter.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "converter.hpp"

bool isConverterUsedAgain(const char* bytes)
{
  int myIntValue = 0;
  Converter::to_type(bytes, myIntValue);
  std::cout << "myIntValue: " << myIntValue << std::endl;
  return true;
}
```

This code does nothing apart from helping me illustrate my problem. When I compile with `g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04) 8.3.0` (in WSL if that's important somehow) I get the following output

```
$g++ main.cpp userofconverter.cpp anotheruserofconverter.cpp
In file included from converter.hpp:13,
                 from userofconverter.cpp:3:
converter.inl: In static member function ‘static void Converter::to_type(const char*, T&)’:
converter.inl:7:31: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
                               ^~
converter.inl:7:52: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
                                                    ^~
converter.inl: In instantiation of ‘static void Converter::to_type(const char*, T&) [with T = int]’:
converter.inl:24:23:   required from here
converter.inl:7:28: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
converter.inl:7:49: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from converter.hpp:13,
                 from anotheruserofconverter.cpp:3:
converter.inl: In static member function ‘static void Converter::to_type(const char*, T&)’:
converter.inl:7:31: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
                               ^~
converter.inl:7:52: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
                                                    ^~
converter.inl: In instantiation of ‘static void Converter::to_type(const char*, T&) [with T = int]’:
converter.inl:24:23:   required from here
converter.inl:7:28: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
converter.inl:7:49: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   value = (T)(*(bytes + 3) << 40 | *(bytes + 3) << 32 | *(bytes + 3) << 24 | *(bytes + 2) << 16 | *(bytes + 1) << 8 | *bytes);
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

In the compilation output I can see twice this message `In instantiation of ‘static void Converter::to_type(const char*, T&) [with T = int]’`

1. Does it mean that the function Converter::to_type is actually being instantiated two times?
2. If so, is there a way to avoid multiple instantiations?

Comment: Yes, with explicit instantiation.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mre]?

Comment: @L.F. That is very minimal to me compared to the whole code I am dealing with. This is the only code I could came up with, to really show the output I am getting.

Comment: @BRabbit27 Start with a new project, add as little code as possible in order to reproduce the problem.  Don’t strip code from the project.  At least that’s how I make [mre]s.

Comment: Notice that int might have less that 64bits (and even less than 32 bits), so you have to use explicitly type such as `std::uint64_t` instead of using implicit `int` promotion with your bit shift.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes all that is also fixed while trying to solve the problem actually presented here. Thanks !

Comment: Left shift of the form `a << b`) has undefined behaviour if `b` is more than the number of bits in `a`.   `bytes` is a `char *` so `*(bytes + 3)` has type `char`.   `*(bytes + 3) << 40` therefore tries to apply a left shift of 40 to a `char`.   No real world implementation has a 40-bit `char` type.

Comment: @Peter: there is integral promotion, so `*(bytes + 3)` is of type int. (but issue with UB remains).

Answer (score 2):

The template will be compiled twice. This is because inline functions are defined in headers and headers aren't compiled so each cpp file must compile its own version of every inline function it uses just in case no other cpp file uses the inline function. However, if the inline function is inlined by the compiler, this is necessary anyway and if the inline function isn't inlined the linker will remove duplicates.

you can create an explicit instantiation for Converter::to_type<int> in a cpp file to stop it from being compiled twice.

```
// file Converter.h
#pragma once

#include <cassert>

class Converter
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  static inline void to_type(const char* bytes, T& val);
  ...
};
extern template void Converter::to_type<int>(const char* bytes, int& val);

...
```

```
// file Converter.cpp
#include "Converter.h"

template void Converter::to_type<int>(const char* bytes, int& val);
```

Comment: The `inline` keyword is redundant on templates so this is more about templates than about `inline`

Answer (score 0):

`Converter::to_type` appears multiple times in the error message as part of the instantiation trace. Why are there two errors in the particular `to_type` instantiation? Probably because you did not use `constexpr` `numberOfBytes` and `if constexpr`, therefore all of the code in `to_type` has to be valid and compiled. If `if constexpr` is not available, you can still emulate it with template specializations.

Comment: constexpr actually removes the error message `In instantiation of ‘static void Converter::to_type(const char*, T&) [with T = int]’` but I guess what I was trying to say is how to avoid the duplicate instantiation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You compiled 3 cpp files, `g++ main.cpp userofconverter.cpp anotheruserofconverter.cpp`, each cpp file in the command line will generate a [Translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c).

Each translation unit will `#include "converter.hpp"` because you told it to, and while compiling those two translation units, both of them spotted warnings and error in `converter.hpp` so you see the same messages.

Yes it can be solved, for example you can compile one file (`main.cpp` for example) and include `userofconverter.cpp` and `anotheruserofconverter.cpp` and it will compile as one translation unit.

Comment: So, it is in fact, instantiating twice the template function `to_type`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Why not?

Comment: @Jarod42 I wouldn't call it lying. Its just an extension, you can easily change it if you'd like, I gave him example based on the question he asked. I don't think you should tell other programmers to not include cpp files, it isn't wrong, its different, and it works, and sometimes compiles a lot faster than creating a bunch of translation units.